# Short events in a long timeline chart with zooming

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, data-visualization

I looked for hours in finding a chart that will be similar to the image that I upload without any result.

I want to implement it in D3.js or other data visualization framework.
I would appreciate if someone will give me a similar example to this kind of graph.

Example of the chart

[image]

Comment: You can start from here: http://bl.ocks.org/dk8996/5449641

Comment: Thanks, it a start but not what I looked for. I want that it will be like a stock chart with time line but in horizontal bars.